# Create a subdomain pointing to RedShift (Route53)

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-redshift, amazon-route53

Hello I currently have a Redshift Cluster and I need to my apps point to a subdomain instead of the Redshift cluster HOST. This redshift cluster is inside a VPC with gateway endpoint type. How do I create a route53 record inside my already existing hosted zone to do this?

Already tried adding a CNAME record and poiting directly to the Redshift host,a but since its inside a VPC does not work.

Answer (score 1):

> An Amazon VPC interface endpoint – Route 53 responds with one or more IP addresses for your interface endpoint.

[Alias](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html) type record may help in this situation